# Request param not picked when @ symbol present in path variable value

Tags: java, spring-boot, http, url

I have a controller as following

```
@GetMapping(value = "/banking/accounts/customer/auth/{uniquePaymentId}")
public void clientAuth(@PathVariable("uniquePaymentId") @NotBlank(message = "uniquePaymentId should not be empty") final String uniquePaymentId,
                       @RequestParam(value = "consentId") final String consentId, final HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
    String clientAuthUrl = openBankingService.getClientAuthUrl(uniquePaymentId, consentId);
    response.sendRedirect(clientAuthUrl);
}
```

when I call the api with url **{{domain}}/v1/banking/accounts/customer/auth/test@test?consentId=value**

get following error

```
{
    "status": "INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR",
    "message": "Required String parameter 'consentId' is not present",
    "errors": [
        "Required String parameter 'consentId' is not present"
    ]
}
```

but when I remove @ from **url(/auth/test@test?consentId=value)** and call everything works fine.
Is @ is reserved ?

Note: I'm using postman for the api call

[image]

Answer (score 2):

`@` must be encoded when used in a URL. The URL-encoded value is `%40`.

Answer (score -1):

Try using below to include special character

```
@GetMapping(value = "/authenticate/google/{id:.+}", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
```

`{.+}` => ".+" allows "." to be included in path varialble in spring controller. Use "@" instead of "." in your case and try.